# Cloud vision Product search api labels

Tags: search, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, vision-api

Can we add labels of our own choice in cloud vision product search API? Source: [Formatting a bulk import CSV](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/csv-format).

Let's say I want to add labels like `category=hello`, `style=world`.

Or is there a fixed domain of `category` and `style` values from which we need to choose?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **you can add the labels as you want** to describe the product.

You can check [in this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/product-search/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.products#Product.FIELDS.product_category) the values allowed for each field.

> **productLabels** - object (KeyValue): Multiple values can be assigned to the same key. One product may have up to 500 productLabels.

The only filed that **you have** to choose the proper values is `product-category`:

> **product-category** - Allowed values are `homegoods-v2`, `apparel-v2`, `toys-v2`, `packagedgoods-v1`, and `general-v1`